# Equivalent parametric solution sets

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, parametric

I have this question that I've never seen before, I've only ever learned about how to find the parametric version of a solution set, but I've never learned how to change it in any way...

I will type out the question as well as include the image

> A system of linear equations has the following solution set (in parametric form):
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 0 \\
> 0
> \end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 0 \\
> -1
> \end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 \\
> 1 \\
> -1
> \end{bmatrix}$$

Which of the following is also a description of this solution set? Select all that apply.

A. $\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-2 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}$

B. $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
-2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

C. $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}$

D. $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
-3 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

E. $\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}$

[image of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvw4p.png)

The answer key in my book says that the answer is A) and D), but no explanation. Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two sets $\{V + tW_1 + sW_2\}$, $\{\widetilde V + t\widetilde W_1 + s\widetilde W_2\}$ representing planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are the same if and only if both of the following conditions hold:

- $N = W_1 \times W_2$ and $\widetilde N = \widetilde W_1 \times \widetilde W_2$ are the same up to scaling (where $\times$ is the cross product)
- $N \cdot V = N \cdot \widetilde V$ (where $\cdot$ is the dot product).

For example, for the solution set in your question, $N = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $N \cdot V = 1$.

For answer A., $$\widetilde N =  \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\-2 \\-2 \end{bmatrix} = (-2) N,$$ so condition 1 is satisfied. Moreover, $$N \cdot \widetilde V = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 0 = N \cdot V,$$ so condition 2 is satisfied. Therefore A. represents the same set as the solution set.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution, this is actually for my linear algebra class that hasn't taught us cross products (and also doesn't teach us it the whole year i think). Would you mind explaining why condition 1 is true (intuitively)?, I assume condition 2 is because of orthogonality which makes sense! Thanks so much for the solution regardless though, I had no idea at all where to start with this before u answered

Comment: Of course! Apologies for using something that you haven't learned yet... Condition 1 says that the normal vectors of the two planes are the same, since $W_1 \times W_2$ is a normal vector to the plane (a normal vector to a plane is a vector perpendicular to the plane). If condition 1 holds then the two sets must be the same or parallel to each other. Condition 2 checks that the distance of the two planes from the origin is the same, ruling out the possibility that they are parallel but not equal.